# Apache location match for certain folder for all virtual hosts

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, wordpress

I have about 200 wordpress installations on my server. i want to disable script execution in /uploads folders. i have written this rule in apache global configuration but its not working.
is there anything else i should do to accomplish this task? i dont want any scripts to run in uploads folder, and in any subfolder in it.

```
<LocationMatch "/wp-content/uploads">
php_flag engine off
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `Match` from the directive and changing to `php_value`.

```
<LocationMatch "/wp-content/uploads">
    php_value engine off
</LocationMatch>
```

You could also set this in `.htaccess` to make it more clear.